# zenity window on top

Tags: zenity

I would like the window produced by zenity to be configured so it is always on top. There does not appear to be an option to enable this. Can someone suggest a source change to the zenity code so that I can get this to work? I want to be able to do
  zenity --ontop "warning"

If there is an alternative which does not involve writing code, I would be interested in this too.

Comment: Does it have to be Zenity itself? You could use [YAD](http://code.google.com/p/yad/) which is a fork of Zenity with an `--on-top` option.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152294/keep-a-zenity-dialog-box-always-on-top-in-foreground

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will keep a zenity Information dialog `on top`.
You can possibly adapt it to your particular needs.
I'm not sure why it needs the `sleep`, but is doesn't work without it.

```
sleep .1 && wmctrl -a Information -b add,above &
WINDOWID=$(xwininfo -root -int | awk '/xwininfo:/{print $4}') \
  zenity --info --text="This --info class dialog is on top of the root window" &
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(sleep 1 && DISPLAY=:0 wmctrl -F -a "Information" -b add,above) & (DISPLAY=:0 zenity --info --title="On Top" --text="Zenity's on top.")
```

Naturally, both zenity and wmctrl need to be installed. The two DISPLAY=:0 portions are probably necessary if you run the script as a cron job because cron's environment is not aware of your X display, dbus or desktop.